I need to understand how matrix multiplication happens in this C++ program
This is the code obtained from an ECS example by Austin Morlan.

class Mat44
{
public:
    Mat44()
    {
        //@formatter:off
        m[0][0] = 1.0f; m[0][1] = 0.0f; m[0][2] = 0.0f; m[0][3] = 0.0f;
        m[1][0] = 0.0f; m[1][1] = 1.0f; m[1][2] = 0.0f; m[1][3] = 0.0f;
        m[2][0] = 0.0f; m[2][1] = 0.0f; m[2][2] = 1.0f; m[2][3] = 0.0f;
        m[3][0] = 0.0f; m[3][1] = 0.0f; m[3][2] = 0.0f; m[3][3] = 1.0f;
        //@formatter:on
    }


    Mat44 operator*(Mat44 const& rhs)
    {
        Mat44 result;

        for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; ++col)
            {
                float sum = 0.0f;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                {
                    sum += m[row][i] * rhs.m[i][col];
                }

                result.m[row][col] = sum;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    Vec4 operator*(Vec4 const& rhs)
    {
        return Vec4(
            (rhs.x * m[0][0]) + (rhs.y * m[0][1]) + (rhs.z * m[0][2]) + (rhs.w * m[0][3]),
            (rhs.x * m[1][0]) + (rhs.y * m[1][1]) + (rhs.z * m[1][2]) + (rhs.w * m[1][3]),
            (rhs.x * m[2][0]) + (rhs.y * m[2][1]) + (rhs.z * m[2][2]) + (rhs.w * m[2][3]),
            (rhs.x * m[3][0]) + (rhs.y * m[3][1]) + (rhs.z * m[3][2]) + (rhs.w * m[3][3]));
    }


    float m[4][4];
};



The questions:

Please explain to me in simple terms what's happening in the for loops? (my understanding: for every row, the columns are fully traversed, a variable sum is declared to store the result of the multiplication, then an index(tracker for the multidimensional array)is set to keep track of every index traversed, essentially a sort of "helper" here. If I'm correct so far, I can't build on from here, perhaps there's a better way to help me understand what's happening here?

Are these the abstractions hidden by the GLM library?

My CPP knowledge is intermediate, I can't understand why the operator overload takes a parameter

And finally, for the Vec4 class, I don't even know what's going on?



Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful to your question if you narrowed the problem down to one detail that you don't understand. Currently, you're asking quite a couple of questions at the same time. It's also unclear how we're supposed to answer a question such as "And finally, for the Vec4 class, I don't even know what's going on?"

If it didn’t take a parameter what would you be multiplying by? You may be better served by a C++ tutorial.

If you have two variables a and b, of a class that have overloaded operator* as a member function, then a * b will be translated as a.operator*(b). If the operator* is overloaded as a non-member function then it would be operator*(a, b). This should really have been taught in a beginners class, book or tutorial.

As for how matrix multiplication works, you need to learn the actual math. Then the code should become quite clear and obvious.

It's not clear what you mean by 2.

@Swift-FridayPie glm the math library, does it do this for us under the hood? Without us having to implement the whole thing as shown in the code sample

@verdy As many other libraries. It's also implemented in GPU itself, if you write shader, you would operate with builtin matrix and vector types as abstractions of GPU instructions. matrix_float4x4 instantiates version of mat which does exactly this. Only it's a template in their case. It's not even under hood, whole thing is in header. For small vectors and matrices loops usually not used..

Translating from one implementation to anoter might be tricky without knowing if it uses main-row or main-column  transformation matrices, e.g. OpenGL for optimization uses transposed version of matrix, storing first column as first row. If a library was optimized for use with OpenGL, its operations may look turned backward compared to mathematical canon.

For operator overloading, if a binary operator is declared as a member of class, it implicitly takes one argument of *this as a first operand, i.e. object itself, and therefore it is declared only with one formal argument. E.g. Mat44 operator*(Mat44 const& rhs) allows following code:
   Mat44 a{}, b{};
   Mat44 c = a * b; 

Mat44::operator* is called in context a with argument b. For left-to-right operator, the type of left operand a defines which operator is called (it's Mat44 in our case), right operand is passed as the argument. Same happens with Mat44::operator*(Vec4 const&).
By analogy, unary operators (except increment) as members are declared without a formal argument at all, becuase they obviously have only one operand. Operator overloading is an essential topic in C++, not optional.
Mat44::operator* represents matrix multiplication. A vector is a case of matrix where one dimension is equal 1 (depending on which, it's a vector column or vector row). It is traditional to represent a vector as a separate type, because of multiple optimizations and rules affecting it and that semantically a vector-column and a vector-row are equivalent.
These aren't "hidden abstractions", these are part common mathematical knowledge.  In a regular curricula you'd get to that before actually learing programming. As a*b is not equal to b*a, if these are matrices, the operator must be a member to ensure order of operations. Computer graphics are heavily mased on linear algebra, esp. vector math.
